# Creation of folders dynamically in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a application in which I have to create folders dynamically on the server.The functionality is this that user click on the folder icon for creating the folder,after that give name to the folder and upload file in it.It is same like we do on `"dropbox.com"`.
So,anybody suggest if there is any kind of example on the internet or any kind of API that is helpful for me. I have search a lot for this but couldn't succeed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

from your controller:

```
  var path = Server.MapPath("~/Directories/YourDirectory");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Comment: I used the Directory.CreateDirectory(path); - part. Worked nicely.